# Sleep,Yield and Join in thread class

Tags: java

Why sleep and yield methods are static in Thread class? but join method is non static.

Can any one explain with example on why sleep and yield are static?

Comment: Do you know what these methods do? Because from that knowledge it's very understandable why they are static/non-static.

Comment: I am new to java. I am not able to understand very clearly on why those methods are static.

Answer (score 1):

They operate on the current thread, unlike `join()` which is called on the thread that you want the current thread to join to.